# Parse.com "access denied" when importing images - Access denied on images (Request failed: forbidden (403))

Tags: android, ios, database, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com and I can't get access to my images after importing a database to a new application in the same account. I have 1 account and in that account I have created 2 apps [1 for production and 1 for development].

The steps I followed:

1. I export a table from the production database (with images) and get it sent to me via email.
2. Then I goto my development app [in same account] and import the data.
3. Importing performs with success but when I make doubleclick on image value (the name of the file is displayed in the cell) I see the xml with "Access denied" in several fields instead of showing the image.

I have looked online and see that this issue occurs when transferring data across accounts but apparently it should work for apps under the same account, however mine is not... any ideas?

PS I have also tried the new "clone" feature but this doesn't allow for data to be cloned yet so I attempted to do this manually and still got same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having an identical issue. If you check the JSON export from your production database you'll notice all the links to you images are correct, Parse is changing them on import so I'm guessing the first part of the URL is an identifier for the DB.

I have found no answer to this. You'd think there would be some way to export all of the images to link with the dev DB or change the access to the images to include the dev DB but there is NO WAY.

I would not recommend using Parse for any serious app development at this point in time.